# Windows 7 sysprep during deploying error

Tags: windows-7, sysprep

I have deployed a windows 7 syspreped image at several machines without any issue.However at a  specific machine I am getting errors.The log is

> 2015-11-05 15:46:56, Error                        [Shell Unattend]
>   CopyProfileDirectory from C:\Users\Administrator failed (0x8007012b)
>   [gle=0x0000012b] 2015-11-05 15:46:56, Error
>   [Shell Unattend] _CopyToDefaultProfile failed (0x8007012b)
>   [gle=0x0000012b] 2015-11-05 15:46:56, Error
>   [Shell Unattend] CopyProfile failed (0x8007012b) [gle=0x0000012b]
>   2015-11-05 16:14:55, Error                        [windeploy.exe]
>   Setup.exe failed, returning exit code [0x1f] 2015-11-05 16:14:55,
>   Error                        [windeploy.exe] Failure occured during
>   online installation.  Online installation cannot complete at this
>   time.; hr = 0x80004005

However this occurs only at a specific machine

Comment: I assume you have ruled out a hardware problem on the only machine that has this problem?

Comment: No I havent.However I cant find out how to determine a HW problem. Clean windows install works and bypassing this error by SHIFT+F10 and changing a registry value.However when I applied another image worked. The only difference was AVG antivirus... I have tested the image on 15~ other different pcs with no problems

Comment: "he only difference was AVG antivirus" - Remove this difference.

Comment: Security software is known to interfere with Sysprep. It blocks Sysprep’s attempts to modify system files, viewing the attempt as malicious. At the very least, you need to disable security software before you Sysprep.